# Navigated event for WebBrowserTask in WP7?

Tags: c#, .net, events, windows-phone-7.1

Is there a way to handle a similar event to the phone:WebBrowser's Navigated event on WP7.1, but for a WebBrowserTask? I want to open a new WebBrowserTask this way:

```
WebBrowserTask task = new WebBrowserTask();
task.Uri = new Uri(url);
task.Show();
```

Then, when the user navigates to a new URL from that WebBrowserTask, I would like to be able to retrieve the new URL she has navigated to from the same class the WebBrowserTask was created. Can I do this without having a WebBrowser element in my View, or having it and linking it somehow to this WebBrowerTask?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WebBrowserTask` launches the native web browser. As a result your application is suspended, there are no 'hooks' available from the native browser that will allow you to detect changes in URL and re-activate your application.

To achieve the effect you are after you need to use the `WebBrowser` control so that your application is not suspended. `WebBrowser` does have navigation events that will support your needs.